# When opening the website, it says it cannot handle the request. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, http, mysqli

I was hoping someone could help me figure why this code is not really working.
When i enter my website (with the GET), it says the server could not handle the request.
Could someone spot any errors?

I'm new to MySQL/MySQLi and PHP as well, so i'm sorry if any part of my code sounds pretty dumb.

Thanks in advance!!!

My table has the following organization:

```
-------------------
   id   |  value   
-------------------
        |          
        |          
-------------------
```

The column 'id' is an INT and the column 'value' is a JSON.

Here's my current code inside a script called "index.php".

```php
<?php
    $database = "...";
    $username = "...";
    $password = "...";
    $servername = "localhost";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: ".$mysqli->connect_error.".");
    }

    header("Content-type: application/json");

    function get($id) {
        if ($id) {
            $query = "SELECT value FROM myTable WHERE id = ?";
            $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

            $statement->bind_param("i", $id);
            $statement->execute();
            $statement->bind_result($result);
            $statement->fetch();
            $statement->close();

            if ($result) {
                return $result;
            }
            else {
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    function set($id, $value) {
        if ($id && $value) {
            $filled = get($id);
            if ($filled) {
                $query = "UPDATE myTable SET value = ? WHERE id = ?";
                $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

                $statement->bind_param("si", $value, $id);
                $statement->execute();
                $statement->bind_result($result);
                $statement->fetch();
                $statement->close();

                if ($result) {
                    return TRUE;
                }
                else {
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
            else {
                $query = "INSERT INTO myTable (id, value) VALUES (?, ?)";
                $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

                $statement->bind_param("is", $id, $value);
                $statement->execute();
                $statement->bind_result($result);
                $statement->fetch();
                $statement->close();

                if ($result) {
                    return TRUE;
                }
                else {
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    $method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

    if ($method == "GET") {
        $result = get($_GET["id"]);
        echo $result;
    }
    elseif ($method == "POST") {
        $result = set($_POST["id"], $_POST["value"]);
        echo $result;
    }

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Check your web server's error log, it should contain a detailed explanation of the issue.

Comment: @AlexHowansky how do i check my server's error log? I'm hosting on hostinger.

Comment: It varies widely, you'll have to check with them.

Comment: @Octonions You might find [this link](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/website/how-to-check-your-website-error-log) helpful. If the instructions there aren't suitable for your setup, look around for instructions that will work for the setup you have. Your error logs are absolutely essential for narrowing down the causes of your errors, especially if you're asking Stack Overflow for help. Learn to get comfortable looking for and reading your error logs because they're arguably going to be your most important tool as a developer.